# how to measure a circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

As we all know we can measure a line with a scale or any instrument but right now I have studied circles and was wondering if there was any way , instrument or method to measure circle i.e the circumferrence without the formula $2πr$.

Comment: Not necessarily mathematical but: a flexible ruler? I've seen them before ...

Comment: [The instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opisometer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure the circumference of a circle without using $C = 2πr $ you need to find a way to make it linear. This can be done by simply wrapping a string around the circumference, cutting it to make it the correct length, then measuring the length of the string.

Comment: Basically you are saying that $c$ =$l$. For a line and then measure by scale.